# missing expression after unary operator '-'

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I wrote a PowerShell script in PowerShell v5.0, and I'm able to execute that script from a batch file with no issue. However when I execute the batch file in Windows 2008 with PowerShell v1.0, I'm getting an error 'missing expression after unary operator '-'.

Can someone enlighten me what is causing the error?

This is the  code in my batch file

```sh
@ECHO OFF
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%SAP_Shell_Script.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%'";
```

Comment: Replace -command with -file and remove the ampersand.

Comment: From what I can tell -command is expecting  a script block `{script block example}` ... I guess it might work if you put squigly brackets around your command `-Command "{& '%PowerShellScriptPath%'}"` ... I haven't tested anything though

Comment: @RobertCotterman: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected. However, your first advice is worth heeding in general: `PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%PowerShellScriptPath%"`

Comment: Hi @mklement0, I have PS version 5.1, and didn't encounter this error in the windows 10 machine.  I tested each line in  powershell  version 1.0 and works fine. however when executing the script through the batch file, this is  were the error happens.

Comment: @RobertCotterman I've tried your suggestion and still have that error. this is what I did
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "{'%PowerShellScriptPath%'}"

Comment: @Veck Understood (I missed that you were talking about Windows _Server_ 2008, which indeed ships with PowerShell 1.0). See if my answer helps. The script-block angle is a red herring, and  `-Command "{'%PowerShellScriptPath%'}"` won't work as intended in any PowerShell version.

Comment: Did you try the -file parameter instead of -command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't guaranteed to solve your problem, but may lead you to a solution:

First - if even possible - it's worth considering updating your very outdated v1.0 PowerShell installation (which came with Windows Server 2008).

Since you've already ruled out that it isn't the script's *content* that is the problem, the implication is that PowerShell's *CLI syntax* must have changed in later versions:

- It sounds like at least one of the parameter names you're using isn't recognized by `powershell.exe` in v1, causing it and all subsequent arguments to be interpreted *as a PowerShell command* (and it is the `-` prefix - then interpreted as an *operator* - that causes the error message).

Troubleshoot as follows:

- Start with `powershell.exe -?` in order to display what parameters are supported in your version.
- Start with a minimal command, then try to add parameters one by one.

  - The following minimal command assumes that you've used `Set-ExecutionPolicy` to allow at least the *current session* (process) to execute scripts; in later PowerShell versions, you'd do that as follow - I don't know if it works in v1.0:

    ```
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Force -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
    ```

Minimal command:

```
PowerShell "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%'"
```

Note that, as with your original command (which works in v5), the assumption is that the value of variable `%PowerShellScriptPath%` doesn't itself contain `'` characters.